# Automate copying captured pictures from ios/android device to DropBox

Tags: android, ios, screenshot, dropbox, device

I want to copy the screenshot captured images from android/ios devices to dropbox.

i have tried [shotdrop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.humayoun.shotdropfree) app in android. By using shotdrop we can save only 100 images to dropbox and after 5 images per day.

So is there any tool or program to copy images from device to dropbox account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Android/iOS - Method 1: Dropbox Camera Upload

**Requirements**: Dropbox App
Although this is the simplest method, it will sync ALL your photos taken via camera, not only your screenshots.
Details: [How do I use Camera Upload? - Dropbox Help](https://www.dropbox.com/help/289/eng)

### Android - Method 2: Dropsync App

**Requirements**: Dropbox App, Dropsync App
Slightly more complicated: After installing Dropsync and connecting it to your Dropbox account, you have to add the folder

> /sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots

as sync source and any Dropbox folder as target. Then you can modify the sync direction, interval or WLAN/mobile sync as needed. The free version is limited to 8MB files and one folder.
Details: [Dropsync (Dropbox Autosync) - Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync)

I can't test any iOS apps due to the lack of an iOS device, but you could look on AppCrawlr.com for alternatives to Dropsync.

Answer (score 0):

IFTTT.com has many recipes for automating such behaviours. In your case these are the candidates that could be useful:

https://ifttt.com/connect/android_photos/dropbox